# Avoiding closure - encapsulating thread variables in a struct

Tags: multithreading, rust

I am writing a simple websocket server named BoltServer based on Rust websocket crate(Code is incomplete, I just started). I am using the example program as the base. However the example programs are not modular (having very long methods). So I am trying to break them up into structs and methods. I want to spawn two threads for each client. One sends messages and the other one receives messages. So here, I want to capture all variables used by the thread in a struct and then call the run method in the impl.

```
extern crate websocket;
extern crate time;
extern crate rustc_serialize;

pub mod ws {
    use std::thread;
    use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
    use std::sync::mpsc;
    use std::net::ToSocketAddrs;
    use websocket;
    use websocket::{Server, Message, Sender, Receiver};
    use websocket::server::Connection;
    use websocket::stream::WebSocketStream;
    use std::str::from_utf8;

    struct BoltUser {
        user_id: u32,
        my_tx: mpsc::Sender<String>,
    }

    struct Broadcaster {
        my_rx: mpsc::Receiver<String>,
    }
    impl Broadcaster {
        fn new(receiver: mpsc::Receiver<String>) -> Broadcaster {
            Broadcaster { my_rx: receiver }
        }
        fn run(self) {
            while let Ok(msg) = self.my_rx.recv() {
                println!("Broadcaster got message: {}", msg);
            }
        }
    }

    struct SocketReader {}
    impl SocketReader {
        fn run(self) {}
    }

    struct SocketWriter {
        my_rx: mpsc::Receiver<String>,
        sender: Sender,
    }
    impl SocketWriter {
        fn run(self) {
            while let Ok(message) = self.my_rx.recv() {
            }
        }
    }

    pub struct BoltServer {
        address: String,
        connected_users: Arc<Mutex<Vec<BoltUser>>>,
    }
    impl BoltServer {
        pub fn new(address: &str) -> BoltServer {
            BoltServer {
                address: address.to_string(),
                connected_users: Arc::new(Mutex::new(vec![])),
            }
        }
        fn handshake(&mut self,
                     connection: Connection<WebSocketStream, WebSocketStream>)
                     -> (SocketWriter, SocketReader) {
            let request = connection.read_request().unwrap();
            // println!("thread-> Accepting request...");
            let response = request.accept();
            let (mut sender, mut receiver) = response.send().unwrap().split();
            let (user_tx, user_rx) = mpsc::channel::<String>();//Create a channel for writer
            let socket_writer = SocketWriter {
                my_rx: user_rx,
                sender: sender,
            };
            let socket_reader = SocketReader {};
            (socket_writer, socket_reader)
        }
        pub fn start(&mut self) {
            println!("Starting");
            let (broadcaster_tx, broadcaster_rx) = mpsc::channel::<String>();
            let broadcaster = Broadcaster::new(broadcaster_rx);
            let handle = thread::Builder::new()
                .name("Broadcaster".to_string())
                .spawn(move || broadcaster.run());

            let server = Server::bind(&*self.address).unwrap();

            let mut user_id: u32 = 0;

            // Block and process connection request from a new client
            for connection in server {
                user_id = user_id + 1;//Create a new user id
                let (socket_writer, socket_reader) = self.handshake(connection);
                thread::Builder::new()
                    .name("Socket writer".to_string())
                    .spawn(move || socket_writer.run());
                thread::Builder::new()
                    .name("Socket reader".to_string())
                    .spawn(move || socket_reader.run());
            }

            handle.unwrap().join();
            println!("Finished");
        }
    }
}
```

The following code gives an idea of what I want to achieve.

```
// Block and process connection request from a new client
for connection in server {
    user_id = user_id + 1;//Create a new user id
    let (socket_writer, socket_reader) = self.handshake(connection);
    thread::Builder::new().name("Socket writer".to_string()).spawn(move || {
        socket_writer.run()
    });
    thread::Builder::new().name("Socket reader".to_string()).spawn(move || {
        socket_reader.run()
    });
}
```

Here I am stuck in the handshake method. I am not able to initialize the `SocketWriter` struct with the sender that I am getting by calling the `split` method in the library. I am getting the following compilation error:

```
    error[E0038]: the trait `websocket::Sender` cannot be made into an object
  --> src/lib.rs:46:9
   |
46 |         sender:Sender,
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `websocket::Sender` cannot be made into an object
   |
   = note: method `send_dataframe` has generic type parameters
   = note: method `send_message` has generic type parameters
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you the immediate problem:

```
46 |         sender:Sender,
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `websocket::Sender` cannot be made into an object
```

First of all, a variable/field can't have a plain trait type (but `&Trait` can be possible), but also the `websocket::Sender` trait is not [object safe](http://huonw.github.io/blog/2015/01/object-safety/); it has generic methods which can't work dynamically (ie vtable methods have to have a fixed type).

Instead, you have to have a concrete type (you could also make it a generic struct).

It's not obvious what the right type is, so I like to get the compiler to tell me.  So first try the simplest possible:

```
    sender: (),
```

The compiler replies with some information:

```
|                       ^^^^^^ expected (), found struct `websocket::client::Sender`
```

Ok, let's plug that in:

```
    sender: websocket::client::Sender,
```

That gives:

```
46 |         sender: websocket::client::Sender,
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected 1 type arguments, found 0
```

Ok, that's a generic type.  Next try:

```
    sender: websocket::client::Sender<()>,
```

Finally it gives us the real type:

```
74 |                sender:sender,
   |                       ^^^^^^ expected (), found enum `websocket::WebSocketStream`
```

So finally we can finish `SocketWriter`:

```
struct SocketWriter {
    my_rx: mpsc::Receiver<String>,
    sender: websocket::client::Sender<websocket::WebSocketStream>,
}
```

There's a following compile error since the `connection` you get is a `Result<>` so you need to check for errors (it compiles if I change to `self.handshake(connection.unwrap())`, but that's obviously not the best practice.

Comment: Thanks. How did you find the concrete type? The websocket API documentation did not mention it.